# Spring-data-redis: cacheManager configuration issue

Tags: spring, caching, redis, spring-data-redis, redis-cache

I am using redis as my spring cache implementation. And the official doc says we should configure the cache manager like this:

```
<!-- Old version -->
<bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.data.redis.cache.RedisCacheManager"
        c:template-ref="redisTemplate">
```

And it works fine when version of jedis = 2.0.0 and version of spring-data-redis = 1.0.2.RELEASE.

But in more recent versions (e.g. jedis = 2.5.2 and spring-data-redis = 1.3.4.RELEASE), the config above is not working. Instead, it throws the an exception, saying "loadCaches must not return an empty Collection".
Then I referred to it and googled it again, and now the configuration file is something like this:

```
<!-- New Version -->
<bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.data.redis.cache.RedisCacheManager"
        c:template-ref="redisTemplate">
    <property name="cacheNames">
        <map>
            <bean id="someid" class="someclass" p:name="somename"/>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Now it doesn't complain about empty collection, but something else about initialization.

So there are another 2 questions here:

1. Inside the cacheNames property, I see others are using "list", "set" and "map". What are the differences?
2. How to configure the bean inside?

I have been struggling with this bean setup for a couple of days.. Could you please help me on them? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

As a hint, please see the `org.springframework.cache.annotation.EnableCaching` annotation.

Inside it talks about the `CacheManager` interface and how it works.

As a quick 'get you going', you need to specify the names of the caches that you will want to be using (such as when you use `@CacheConfig(cacheNames='...')` or `@Cacheable(value = '...')`. The idea is that you are creating logical groupings of related 'things' to be cached, ie: Books, Cars, Loans, etc.

In a BookService, you would use something like `@CacheConfig(cacheNames='Books')`.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the similar issue on using Jedis with spring-data-redis. One of the finding which I have is, spring-data-redis is very **specific** about Jedis version. For my case, **Spring-data-redis 1.5.0.RELEASE** is compatible with **Jedis 2.6.2**.

For your case, as refer to the link below, look for compile dependencies section, you will find out **1.3.4.RELEASE** is compatible with **Jedis 2.4.1**. I believe your problem will be solve once you change your POM file Jedis version.

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-redis/1.3.4.RELEASE